# Use Visual Studio 2013 community version for developing SharePoint apps

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

Can we use Visual Studio 2013 community version for developing SharePoint apps?

What tools we need to install then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition to build both SharePoint Apps and SharePoint Solutions. Just follow the steps under "Set up your environment" found here: http://dev.office.com/getting-started

[image]